# PCA on MNIST dataset results in very poor performance

Tags: svm, performance, multiclass-classification

I am trying to build a model for classifying MNIST dataset using SVM. With raw features I am getting accuracy of around 94% (using linear kernel).

When I tried it with PCA, with different number of components (35,50,250,500) I am getting accuracy around 11%.

What can possibly the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few thing that you may be doing, but worth mentioning.

Did you "whiten" your data---mean center and normalize by the standard deviation? This step may be implementation-dependent.
http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/PCA

Did you check to see how much variablility was explained by the number of chosen parameters? For images +80% is common.

Make sure you understand the implementation of the PCA you are using. It always confuses me by the terminology different implementations uses, e.g. score, rotation, etc. I suggest following a tutorial and matching their output with your implementation to get a deeper understanding.
http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2015_pca_in_3_steps.html

Your model is now built on transformed data. To predict make sure you are using these same transformations on the new input data.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please read up on what exactly is a PCA algorithm and when can it be used and what purpose does it solve.

Just throwing it on a problem and expect it to improve your results would work most of the time.

PCA reduces the features in the dataset into dimensions, and it is for the user to select the number of dimensions he/she want to use in the model as features.

So, [choosing the right number of features](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44060/choosing-number-of-principal-components-to-retain) to use or eliminate from the model would dictate your accuracy.